# How to redirect www.mydom.com to mydom.com

Tags: apache, dns, cpanel, whm, system-administration

I have a dedicated server with WHM/cPanel and hosting multiple domains on Linux.

For one of my domains, I'd like to get all http://www.mydom.com traffic to automatically go to http://mydom.com

This needs to happen for all subdirectories, files etc. e.g. http://www.mydom.com/aFile.php should go to http://mydom.com/aFile.php 
Other subdomains such as img.mydom.com should still go to img.mydom.com and not be redirected.

How can I accomplish this? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup redirection code in your .htaccess file to redirect your all traffic from www to non-www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work! :( Already tried this from https://yoast.com/how-to-remove-www-from-your-url-with-mod_rewrite/

Comment: @user1322921 Not sure about this .. Just give a try replacing `[last,redirect=301]` with `[P]`